# Parsing Windows Event Logs stored in syslog-ng system with multi-lines and tabs

Tags: bash, powershell, awk, sed, syslog

I am trying to parse through a couple hundred gigs of Windows event logs that have not been formatted using SNARE, NXlog, or Adiscon (I am not sure how they shipped them to the syslog server).

The problem I am running into is determining the best/most efficient way to parse through a multi-line, multi-tabbed Windows event file. I don't have the corresponding EVTX file (it is just a log file).

My goal is to get each event onto one line, with no tabs so that I can parse through it easier using grep and awk.

`tr -d "\n\r" < windows.log` gets all of the content on one line (removes newlines) and now I would need to strip tabs (tabs less important than new lines) and figure out a way to add a new line every time BEFORE "Jan 14" is seen.

There is probably be a better way to do this with Python, Perl, or Powershell, but I am limited in experience there.

Example log file:

```
Jan 14 00:00:02 server.host.com MSWinEventLog    5       Security        22159648        Sun Jan 13 23:59:35 2019        4634    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing             N/A     Audit Success   server.host.com  12545   An account was logged off.

Subject:
        Security ID:            S-1-5-21-3015042641-2194367929-112691256-2051
        Account Name:           SVCACCT
        Account Domain:         MYDOMAIN
        Logon ID:               0xD7FC64F5

Logon Type:                     3

This event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer.

Jan 14 00:00:02 server.host.com  MSWinEventLog    5       Security        22159649        Sun Jan 13 23:59:35 2019        4634    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing             N/A     Audit Success   server.host.com   12545   An account was logged off.

Subject:
        Security ID:            S-1-5-21-3015042641-2194367929-112691256-12106
        Account Name:           SVCACCT2
        Account Domain:         MYDOMAIN
        Logon ID:               0xD7FC600A

Logon Type:                     3

This event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer.
```

Example log file condensed:

```
Jan 14 00:00:02 server.host.com MSWinEventLog    5       Security        22159648        Sun Jan 13 23:59:35 2019        4634    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing             N/A     Audit Success   server.host.com  12545   An account was logged off. Subject: Security ID:            S-1-5-21-3015042641-2194367929-112691256-2051 Account Name:           SVCACCT Account Domain:         MYDOMAIN Logon ID:               0xD7FC64F5 Logon Type:                     3 This event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer.

Jan 14 00:00:02 server.host.com MSWinEventLog    5       Security        22159648        Sun Jan 13 23:59:35 2019        4634    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing             N/A     Audit Success   server.host.com  12545   An account was logged off. Subject: Security ID:            S-1-5-21-3015042641-2194367929-112691256-2051 Account Name:           SVCACCT2 Account Domain:         MYDOMAIN Logon ID:               0xD7FC64F5 Logon Type:                     3 This event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we remove all control characters. Then we search for "Jan 14" and add a newline before it. Finally, we call `tr` with the `-s` flag which replaces instances of repeated characters with a single character. I am not quite sure how efficient this is but it might get you started.

```
tr -d "[:cntrl:]" < windows.log | sed 's/Jan 14/\'$'\n&/g' | tr -s " "
```

**Result**

```
Jan 14 00:00:02 server.host.com MSWinEventLog 5 Security 22159648 Sun Jan 13 23:59:35 2019 4634 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing N/A Audit Success server.host.com 12545 An account was logged off.Subject: Security ID: S-1-5-21-3015042641-2194367929-112691256-2051 Account Name: SVCACCT Account Domain: MYDOMAIN Logon ID: 0xD7FC64F5Logon Type: 3This event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer.
Jan 14 00:00:02 server.host.com MSWinEventLog 5 Security 22159649 Sun Jan 13 23:59:35 2019 4634 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing N/A Audit Success server.host.com 12545 An account was logged off.Subject: Security ID: S-1-5-21-3015042641-2194367929-112691256-12106 Account Name: SVCACCT2 Account Domain: MYDOMAIN Logon ID: 0xD7FC600ALogon Type: 3This event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer.
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Thanks so much for your response!

Comment: This should work enough! Sometimes I wanted to replace the tabs with a space and I was wondering if there was a way to keep the Jan but I can just insert it at the beginning of each line, but I can def work with this. I did not know about [:cntrl:], thanks for that. And this is why I need to get better at sed. Thank you sir!

Comment: You got me from 8.5 mil lines down to just over 4k. I'll be able to parse through it better now. Many thanks!

Comment: It's always a great feeling when so many lines become so much less! I also updated my code, since you want to keep the Jan 14, so we use `sed 's/Jan 14/\'$'\n&/g' ` instead

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get every record squeezed onto 1 line and then trying to analyze it, just handle each 12-line block as a single record. For example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    gsub(/\r/,"")
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    lineNr = (NR - 1) % 12 + 1
}
lineNr == 1 {
    f["hd"] = $0
}
lineNr ~ /[45679]/ {
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    f[tag] = val
}
lineNr == 11 {
    f["tl"] = $0
    for (tag in f) {
        print tag, "=", f[tag]
    }
    print "-------"
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
tl = This event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer.
Logon ID = 0xD7FC64F5
Logon Type = 3
Account Name = SVCACCT
Security ID = S-1-5-21-3015042641-2194367929-112691256-2051
hd = Jan 14 00:00:02 server.host.com MSWinEventLog    5       Security        22159648        Sun Jan 13 23:59:35 2019        4634    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing             N/A     Audit Success   server.host.com  12545   An account was logged off.
Account Domain = MYDOMAIN
-------
tl = This event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer.
Logon ID = 0xD7FC600A
Logon Type = 3
Account Name = SVCACCT2
Security ID = S-1-5-21-3015042641-2194367929-112691256-12106
hd = Jan 14 00:00:02 server.host.com  MSWinEventLog    5       Security        22159649        Sun Jan 13 23:59:35 2019        4634    Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing             N/A     Audit Success   server.host.com   12545   An account was logged off.
Account Domain = MYDOMAIN
-------
```

With that approach you can simply refer to every field by it's name for printing or analysis. You can extend the above to map all of the separate fields on the first line into separate tags/values e.g.

```
lineNr==1 {
    f["timestamp"] = $1 " " $2 " " $3
    ...
}
```

or with a regexp match or whatever makes sense. Once you[ve done the above it becomes absolutely trivial to analyze or print whatever you like in the rest of the script.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response and time you took to create it. The only problem is, the log lines are not always 12 lines long, they are variable. That is why I am trying to find a way to get the content between "Jan" and "Jan".

Comment: You're welcome and that's easy to fix if you provide sample input that's more realistic, i.e. isn't always 12 lines long. Looking for "Jan" doesn't sound like a great idea since, obviously, it doesn't work when you get into Feb and there's what appears to be some free text in there which could probably start with "Jan".